# When coding a quiz program, can I code each quiz in a separate project and add them at the end? Or must I create them in a one project from the start?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm creating a simple GUI quiz program in Java. (I’m coding in Java Swing using Eclipse.) I have 10 kinds of quizzes in mind ---- fill in the blanks, multiple choice questions, etc. Instinctively I felt it’s probably not a good idea to try and code the whole program as a single project from the start.

So after coding the login page, quiz  list, etc., I created just one kind of quiz in the project.  So when I ran the program and clicked the first item in the quiz list, the quiz ran.

Then I copied and pasted the whole project and gave it another name. Then deleted the quiz and coded another kind of quiz there.

It felt comfortable to keep the program small like that. The idea was the copy paste all the quiz classes into a single project when everything was ready. It worked fine when I did that.

I got a problem when I had to make a few changes to the code in the quiz list class. I had to open the quiz list class in all the projects and change it. It was tedious. I realized I didn’t know the proper way of creating a program like a quiz.

Could anyone tell me what’s the best approach if one’s making a quiz like program? Should I create all the quizzes in a single project from the start? Or should I develop them one by one and add them together at the end? If both are OK, what would be the pros and cons? Thank you!

PS

Also, I’m reading about modular programming now. I am going to break off some parts of the program like my custom audio player class and add it to the build path for all the projects. But I can’t see how I can break off a class like the quiz list class.  Sure, I can have it in one project and link all the other projects with quizzes to it. But then it’s the same as creating the program in a single project from the beginning. I won’t be able to run each quiz separately to test.

I understand this must be a basic question but I just haven’t been able to find an answer online. I’m not even sure what to search for. Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: Are the classes specific to one kind of quizz plentifull? do they exchange with the main/common part in a different way? if there are few classes with basic exchange with the main part, one project with several packages would do it

Comment: Not plenty. Each quiz has basically three classes. One class is for the GUI and what the components do. Another gets data from the database and sets them on the GUI. The third class checks the answer. They all interact with the common part in the same way. So if I understand you correctly, I should just keep them all in a single project. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

**Don't create a new project for every Quiz!** Seperating your code into multiple programs is a structured programming thing.

In OOP, like Java, we organize our code parts using `class`es and `interface`s.
You could have an `interface` Quiz and multiple (maybe `abstract`) classes. All following code is just a rough concept:

```
public interface Quiz
{
    JPanel getContent();
}
```

```
public class MultipleChoiceQuiz implements Quiz
{
    @Override
    public JPanel getContent()
    {
        //define the content here somehow
        return content;
    }

    //maybe some extra method here?
}
```

```
public class BlankFillQuiz implements Quiz
{
    @Override
    public JPanel getContent()
    {
        //define the content here somehow
        return content;
    }

    //maybe some extra method here?
}
```

So now you can have a method in the controller which is called every time the user wants to submit their quiz-input.

```
public void submit()
{
    if (validateInputs())
    {
        //Correct.
        nextQuiz();
    }
    else
    {
        //WRONG!
    }
}
```

Where `nextQuiz()` advances the quiz by one. For example:

```
private void nextQuiz()
{
    setQuiz(currentQuizIndex + 1);
}

private setQuiz(int quizIndex)
{
    List<Quiz> quizList = //a list initialized containing all quizzes;
    mainPanel.setContent(quizList.get(quizIndex).getContent());
    currentQuizIndex = quizIndex;
}
```

I could go on and on..

Comment: Thanks a lot for typing a detailed reply. :) So you suggest that I should just do it in a single project. I'll do that. I think I understand what you've said. I'm still quite new to Java. Don't know enough basics yet. I've structured the program like this: Each quiz has three classes. The first class is for the GUI and what the components do. The second gets data from the database and sets them on the GUI. The third class checks the answer and does something depending on what the answer. All the quiz GUI classes are in one package. I've done the same for the other two kinds of classes too.

Comment: @Dan That's alright. I'd just somehow couple these classes tightly together then.

Comment: So that's alright then? Thanks a lot. I'm just finding my way through Java. It's good to get the opinions of those who know more.